# Missing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor when installing Visual Studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to get [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to run in Visual Studio by using [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pvdstel.scrcpy) and determine if I can extend its features.

Unable to install a VSIX extension for Visual Studio 2019

Installation fails indicating:

[image]

I updated the `<InstallationTarget>` and `<Dependency>` as per [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/885615c6-8e00-48dc-a4ba-5828121afe23/i-am-trying-to-upgrade-my-extension-to-vs-2019-and-the-vsix-installer-only-lists-2017-as-an-option?forum=vsx),

> You need to change InstallationTarget to [15.0,17.0) and Prerequisite
>   to [15.8.27729.1,).

I unzipped the .vsix file, updated the `extension.vsixmanifest` file to the following:

```
<Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[15.0,17.0)" />
  </Installation>
  <Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" Version="[4.5,)" />
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.15.0" DisplayName="Visual Studio MPF 15.0" Version="[15.0]" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Prerequisites>
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.8.27729.1,)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
  </Prerequisites>
```

Zipped the directory, renamed to *.vsix, tried to install again.

The installer now recognizes Visual Studio 2019, begins installing but fails, missing `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor`.

```
12/11/2019 5:25:00 PM - Beginning to install extension to Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (2)...
12/11/2019 5:25:02 PM - Install Error : Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.MissingReferencesException: This extension cannot be installed because the following references are missing:
-Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.EngineUtilities.EnsureNoMissingReferences(IEnumerable`1 missingRefs)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.PackageInstaller.PrepareEngineInstall(IDependencyGraph dGraph, IDependencyComparisonSeed seed, Component vsixComponent, Boolean isProductComponent, Int32& totalInstallationSteps)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress, Version targetedVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
```

Suggestions on next steps please?

Comment: Prerequisite version for  CoreEditor is usually set to [15.0,)

Comment: Apart from the changes of the `extension.vsixmanifest` file, please also change the `"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor":"[15.0,16.0)"` of the `catalog.json` file to **[15.0,17.0)**. Let me know if it works:)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Missing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor when installing
>   Visual Studio extension

l think the main issue is that you did not modify the version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor`to support Visual Studio 2019 in `catalog.json` file. So when you run the vsix file, it will monitor and then run the file is missing the corresponding VS2019 `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Com ponent. CoreEditor`.

**Solution**

Apart from the changes to `extension.vsixmanifest` file,
please also change `"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor":"[15.0,16.0)"` in `catalog.json` file to **[15.0,17.0)**.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: but where is catalog.json?

Comment: @Mr.D It's inside the VSIX file. You can extract VSIX files using any tool that can open ZIP files like 7-zip.

Answer (score 13):

**Update** for [VS2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/update-visual-studio-extension?view=vs-2022) to enable installation you have to modify
extension.vsixmanifest

```xml
<Installation>
   <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[15.0,17.0)">
      <ProductArchitecture>x86</ProductArchitecture>
   </InstallationTarget>
   <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[17.0,18.0)">
      <ProductArchitecture>amd64</ProductArchitecture>
   </InstallationTarget>
</Installation>
```

---

As [Perry Qian-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59302783/4423572) said when using older vsix packages on newer Visual studio you should update **[14.0,16.0]** to whatever is the current VS version **[14.0,xx.x]**.

Within files

- catalog.json
- manifest.json
- extension.vsixmanifest

Comment: Where are this files located on disk?

Comment: @Manolo you need to download the VSIX extension you want. Then unzip it to folder, change the files mentioned above. Save and zip the folder again with the ending *.vsix. Then you can insatll it

Comment: It works fine in visual studio 2017 community, thanks

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative, you may want to modify the Visual Studio Installation (with Visual Studio Installer) and include the "Visual Studio extension development". Odds are, this toolset will fix the missing requirement issue.
[image: Visual Studio Installer Toolset]

Comment: I have this installed and I still get the error mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 3):

For **VS2022** you need to edit the version string to **[17.0,18.0)** as in:

`"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor": "[17.0,18.0)"`

Comment: I still can't install after this, I get the error "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.MissingReferencesException: This extension cannot be installed because the following references are missing:
-Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor)"